# VBA Overwriting first cell in loop

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement, timer

I started programming with VBA and of course I face some issues.
I will try to explain as good as I can my issue, if not clear please let me know.

I am trying at specific time during the day to copy the current spot rate of a currency pair and paste it to another sheet in a column. Then for the next time step, I want the new spot rate to copy-paste to that column in the next row and so on. 
The problem that I have at the moment is that, if I choose a time e.g. 09:00 I can copy-paste that spot rate, but tomorrow at the same time 09:00 my code will go back to the first cell and overwrite the value. This I do not want. I would like to keep pasting in the next cell. I am attaching my code so you can see my problem. It starts where I define i = 1.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro

    alertTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05") 'hh:mm:ss
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "Macro1"

    Dim LTime1 As Date, LTime2 As Date
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim USDJPY As Worksheet, EURUSD As Worksheet, Allrates As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With Range("P17")
        .Value = Date
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yy"
    End With

    Set Allrates = Sheets("Allrates")
    Set EURUSD = Sheets("EURUSD")
    Set EURGBP = Sheets("EURGBP")


    LTime1 = TimeValue("09:00:00")
    LTime2 = TimeValue("12:00:00")

    i = 1
    If Range("P20") = LTime1 Then
        Allrates.Range("B18").Copy EURGBP.Cells(i, 1)
    End If

    i = i + 1

    If Range("P20") = LTime2 Then
        Allrates.Range("B18").Copy EURGBP.Cells(i, 1)
    End If


ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EURGBP.Cells(i, 1)` needs to be `EURGBP.Cells(EURGBP.RANGE("A10000").End(xlUp).Row+1, 1)`

Comment: no problem, you can change the 10000 to be `EURGBP.Rows.Count` also

Comment: you mean like that? EURGBP.Cells(EURGBP.Rows.Count.End(xlUp).Row+1, 1)

Comment: also the "i" i dont need them any more i guess, i can delete them, correct? thanks mate for your help, vm appreciated!!

Comment: No need for the i's :)  Not a problem.